# R programming: adding a column that was deleted?

Tags: r, addition

I removed a column from my dataframe. I realized that I actually need this column. Is there a function to re-add this column?

Thank you!

Comment: Load the data again?

Comment: There is no "undo" command in R, no.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TimeMachine/index.html).

Comment: Seriously, though, R keeps a history of commands, so you should be able to replicate what you've done in R to a point. Check out `?history`.

Answer (score 1):

If you had originally read in your data frame, then one option is that you can simply reload.  For example:

`x <- read.csv(...)`

will update x with everything you had originally loaded in.